# PDF embed on github page does not work: 404 error occurs

Tags: html, github, pdf

I want to embed the pdf file as follows: https://www.codexworld.com/embed-pdf-document-file-in-html-web-page/

However, I just merely get the 404 file not found error.

Here is my github link:

https://github.com/gyulab/gyulab.github.io/blob/master/_posts/Projects/2021-10-15-ms482_midterm.md

https://gyulab.github.io//projects/2021/10/15/ms482_midterm.html

I have tried the following codes(the permanent link, local link, etc.), but all of these did not work.

```
<embed src="https://gyulab.github.io/_posts/Projects/MS482_Report_20180583_Gyujun Jeong.pdf" type="application/pdf" />
```

```
<embed src="MS482_Report_20180583_Gyujun Jeong.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px" />
```

```
<embed src="https://github.com/gyulab/gyulab.github.io/blob/853df1ac46c7fecab4ca7c98d2a2d70a4f1860c7/_posts/Projects/MS482_Report_20180583_Gyujun%20Jeong.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px" />
```

How could I solve this problem?

I tried to change the link variation stated on stackoverflow and does not work.